# How to resolve "Package Google Authenticator 1.2.1 was restored using .NETFramework", but I do not want to upgrade to latest version (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to resolve?

> Package 'GoogleAuthenticator 1.2.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

But I don't want to upgrade to latest version (C#)

[image]

Comment: The version you want to use is for .net framework, however you are using .netcore. since you dont want to upgrade, there is nothing that can help you, the end

Answer (score 0):

The version of the nugget package you're using is incompatible with .NET Core 2.1.

However, Visual Studio is trying to use the available target .NET frameworks, which may not be compatible with your target framework as stated. Since you don't want to upgrade, it should compile successfully even with the warnings but there's no guarantee that the package will work.